# Apache redirect to https://www and then proxy to localhost

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, proxy, plesk

I've got a node.js app running on `localhost:8180`.

I want the app to be accessible from the web only via https://www.example.com.

The goal is to redirect all traffic going to `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`.

I have access to the Plesk panel v12.5.30. In this panel I can configure separate .htaccess rules for http and https requests. The panel looks like this:

[Plesk Apache directives panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lQdk.png)

Can I achieve my goal using this panel?

I've tried the following rules for http and https but get a proxy error.

*http*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 [L,R=301]`
```

*https*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8180$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8180/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend using Nginx Directives Instead like this:

```
if ($scheme != https) {
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

[image: Redirect 301 using Nginx]

You can also try a better compatibility htaccess code on top of all your `.htaccess` file codes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The thing is that redirecting http to https with www works perfectly. I just have problems with conditional redirecting in the https version. It should work like this: no www -> redirect to www, has www -> proxy to localhost

Comment: Yes, you can use nginx condition as demonstrated above: `if($scheme != https)`

You can try location block: https://serverfault.com/questions/586586/nginx-redirect-via-proxy-rewrite-and-preserve-url

Comment: You can try location block: https://serverfault.com/questions/586586/nginx-redirect-via-proxy-rewrite-and-preserve-url